# Boot problem: weird sound

Tags: windows-xp, boot, audio

Here are the specs to put things into context:

- ECS P4M800PRO-M478 (V1.0)
- Intel P4 "Northwood" 2.8C GHz (HT) Socket 478
- 2x 512 MB PC2-4200 DDR2-533 RAM
- Visiontek Radeon HD 3650 512 MB DDR2 AGP
- Maxtor 120 GB SATA HDD
- The Best Power 500 W ATX PSU

Anyways, it's not booting Windows XP SP3 properly. Specifically, there is a sound when it fails to boot and the computer automatically restarts. You can listen to the sound [here](http://s276.photobucket.com/albums/kk25/instantnoodles123/Problems/?action=view&current=bootproblem_0001.flv).

What could be the problem?

**EDIT 1:** Well, it seems that the machine wasn't even completely booting up the BIOS screen with the memory tests & storage device detection. Also, after seeing [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KN6_-8fYHo0&feature=related), the little click upon restart seems to be the same as the one I'm hearing. Perhaps it is actually my motherboard? (Specifically, blown capacitors? Is it fixable?)

**EDIT 2:** I decided to not use my DVD-RAM (IDE) drive, and it booted up without a problem. I don't know if this is the solution to my problem.

**SOLUTION... EDITED:** *I've booted several times successfully without error after removing a DVD-RW drive that was connected to the computer. That loud scraping sound near the beginning of the sound clip was actually the drive (which isn't particularly normal for a drive) and after removing the drive, everything is very smooth. Now... the find a new DVD-RW drive.* Ignore italicized text, which was thought to be the original solution. The ACTUAL problem was the power supply... something was "clicking" inside there and I swapped in a new power supply and it runs perfectly.

Comment: It sounds like somethings dragging. How many times did it reboot in that video?

Comment: One boot. However, I just was trying to boot it now and it didn't make much of a sound when it did reboot.

Comment: Have you tried a known hard drive and see if it's the hard drive. That's the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very scary sound :D

it a failing had drive (the loud click symptom) he's also saying he's too old :)

this is an article from Wikipedia about the [Click of death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_of_death)

Comment: Refer to **EDIT 2**. However, I just downloaded HD Tune and there are only two SMART attributes with warnings. Doesn't seem particularly serious and I may swap the cable to see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Check the manual for the motherboard (you can find it online from ECS if you don't have the paper one anymore). The beep codes are going to be listed under troubleshooting.

Comment: How is it a beep code?? There's normally two beeps... that "click" at the end is NOT normal; that's when it reboots.

Comment: Honestly, the flash clip wouldn't play (using linux here), so I had to guess what you were referring to.

Comment: Oh... can't you download Flash in Linux??

Comment: I have Flash installed, from Adobe, and youtube works just fine. Your clip or photobucket doesn't work well, for whatever reason.